# Javascript works in Firefox and IE, but not Chrome

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome

I had a web page that I thought had way too much content showing at one time, so I wrote some JavaScript to hide a bunch of images until they were needed.  At the bottom of said page I have a link that says, "Click here for Screen Shots!" When clicked the JS will display a previously hidden span that contains all the screenshots.  The link text is changed to, "Click here to hide Screen shots." This works in IE and Firefox, but for some reason not in Chrome (in chrome I have to click the hide link 3 times before the span is hidden again).  The code is fairly simple, but I cant figure out what is wrong with it.  Any ideas?

The JS:

```
$('#show').click(function(){
$('#Screenies').show('slow');
$('#show').hide();
$('#hide').show();
});

$('#hide').click(function(){
$('#Screenies').hide('slow');
$('#hide').hide();
$('#show').show();
});
```

The Html:

```
 <p id="show" style="cursor:pointer; color:Navy"><u>Click here for sceenshots!</u></p>
 <p id="hide" style="cursor:pointer; color:Navy"><u>Hide sceenshots</u></p>
 <span id="Screenies">
      [Image links in here]
 </span>
```

Edit:
Forgot to mention I am using Jquery 1.6

Comment: I suspect the hide animation has something to do with it. Can you try without it?

Comment: If you add an `alert()` in each method does it comes up in chrome on the first two clicks?

Comment: Download firebug for chrome and run a console.log() function to to ensure that the function is running when you click it, or alert works.... :P

Comment: @Mrchief The show function makes the span visible as expected.

Comment: @Peppered The alert is fired each time the link is clicked

Comment: @Trevor: Chrome developer tools as it's own console. So `console.log()` works without firebug:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the fact that you are animating a span element - don't ask me why. But if you are using semantic markup you should really be using a div to hold your images. I re-factored your code as well, so now you need only 1 link.

```
$('#show').toggle(function(){
    $('#Screenies').show('slow');
    $('#show').text('Hide');
}, function(){
    $('#Screenies').hide('slow');
    $('#show').text('Show');
});
```

If you don't know about the jQuery toggle function [read this article](http://tomsbigbox.com/using-jquerys-toggle-function/), the rest of the code simply animates the element in and then changes the link text based on the current state.

Comment: Why do you consider a `span` to be non-semantic in this case? Bearing in mind that an `img` element is a replaced, naturally in-line, element and so can be contained, validly, within a `span` (in-line element). If there's a large number of images then ***perhaps*** a list would be more-semantic...

Comment: Because it is an inline element, I would say that the image links are separate because there a number of them, and the span is not wrapped in any other block element.

Comment: Ok, changing the span to a div worked.  Also, thanks for refactoring the code ^_^  Much cleaner now.

Comment: Just read your edit, yes I would say a list would be a better option in this case, but a span just feels out of place.

Comment: Given the posted code I'd suggest that a `ul` or `ol` would be more appropriate, but I'm not convinced that a `span` is not semantic in this case. Obviously this is *hugely* subjective, though (and I'm certainly not down-voting for that difference of opinion...).

Comment: Good catch, Tom!  You could always force the span to `display:block` or `inline-block` as well.

Comment: I do agree a list would be better, and I agree that the subject is subjective, but I just feel wrapping a bunch of links inside of an inline element doesn't make the greatest amount of sense, but as you said it's subjective.

Comment: In the [Image links here] part of the code it actually does have a list that is used by another Jquery plugin.  I just wrapped it all in a span to make it easier to hide.

Comment: Right, well if there is a list inside of it, what is the need for the span element? Surely you could just add an ID to your list element and show/hide that?

Comment: I did try it, but for some reason it wasn't working.  The other plugin required the list to have an id with a specific name.  Maybe the plugin was overwriting my hide function.  I really don't know.  Also, that toggle function is really useful.  Thanks for showing it to me.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome probably can't find the elements at the time the code runs. It's a good idea to wrap that code in a document.ready event, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#show').click(function(){
$('#Screenies').show('slow');
$('#show').hide();
$('#hide').show();
});

$('#hide').click(function(){
$('#Screenies').hide('slow');
$('#hide').hide();
$('#show').show();
});
});
```

That did the trick for me.

Comment: it is in a document ready.  I guess I should have included that in the code sample